# BLOB update in Oracle 10G for German language

Tags: oracle, ascii, blob

I have a text that I need to update in a column of type BLOB.
The text is in German language with points marked by bullets.

I tried using the below update statement.

```
update note_temp
set body_tx = to_blob(RAWTOHEX('Ihr vorläufiges Kennwort [password]
•    Ihre Zugangscodes dürfen'))
where note_id = 81
```

This update statement is working fine for english language.
But when I am trying this for German language, ä characters becomes some gibberish characters and also the bullets are missing.

Can anybody help me to update this.

Thanks
Nirmalya

Comment: Why are you storing plain text in a BLOB column? You should use a CLOB column instead.

Comment: The table structure is like this in live environment of the application and I cannot change it.

Comment: You could try `rowtonhex` so that the character encoding is preserved. But that is another ugly workaround. You should really fix your application to use the correct data type.

Comment: rawtonhex is truncating all the characters and text after the first bullet.
Besides I don't bother if this is an ugly workaround, since this is a one time activity. I am doing this to fix an issue related to text sent in automated emails.

Comment: How do you normally insert into this field, and how do you retrieve and use the text later? Wondering if you might be looking for `dbms_log.converttoblob`, but not sure if that would be compatible with your `rawtohex` - guess I'm not sure I really understand what you're doing... What database and national character set are you using?

Comment: I found an alternative way to get this done. I copied the entire text in a text editor (notepad++, textpad, wordpad etc) and then uploaded it as a file in the specific row/column through Toad or SqlDeveloper from Schema Browser.
I don't know why it worked or why it was meant to work but my purpose was solved.

Comment: @AlexPoole : The scenario was like this. There was an email body stored in our database. This email body is sent out fro password reset emails from the application. The url for resetting the password which is mentioned in the email body needed updating. Hence I had to update the text of the email body. The DB is Oracle 10G and character set is UTF-8. I didn't get the opportunity to try dbms_log.converttoblob. I'll try it once I get back from vacation.